# Unable to mount bucket with gcsfuse on Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run, gcsfuse

With the second generation runtime of Google Cloud Run, it's now possible to mount Google Storage Buckets using gcsfuse.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-fuse

The python3 example is working fine. Unfortunately, I keep getting this error with my Dockerfile:

```
bin/fusermount: failed to open /dev/fuse: Permission denied
mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: running /bin/fusermount: exit status 1
```

[image: screenshot]

Dockerfile

```
# https://github.com/chiaen/docker-gcsfuse
FROM golang:1.17.5-alpine as gcsfuse
RUN apk add --no-cache git
ENV GOPATH /go
RUN go get -u github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse

FROM composer:2 as vendor
COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock
RUN composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-interaction --prefer-dist

FROM craftcms/nginx:7.4

ENV MNT_DIR /mnt/gcs

USER root
RUN apk add --no-cache mysql-client postgresql-client ca-certificates fuse nano sudo tini bash

RUN mkdir -p $MNT_DIR
RUN chown www-data:www-data $MNT_DIR
USER www-data

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data --from=vendor /app/vendor/ /app/vendor/
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . .
COPY --from=gcsfuse /go/bin/gcsfuse /usr/local/bin
COPY supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisor.conf
```

Since there are a few files, I put all the files into a github repo.
https://github.com/internetztube/cloud-run-persistent-storage-issue

Comment: I followed the tutorial in the doc, and it works for me: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-fuse#defining_your_environment_configuration_with_the_dockerfile

Comment: The example in the documentation is working for me as well. Problem is that I need PHP and NGINX in the container. I strongly orientated myself on the example and therefore it should work the same way, but it doesn't. @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: 1) Note this line **COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . .**  You have not specified **WORKDIR** in your container. You might be changing file permissions in the container depending on what files are located in the source directory. That might not fix your issue, but should be corrected.

Comment: 2) You are running the **gcsfuse.sh** script from supervisor. However, you have changed the USER to **www-data**. You are getting a permission error on **/dev/fuse**. As a test, change the USER from **www-data** to **root** temporarily to see if that is the actual issue.

Comment: @JohnHanley I removed the `USER www-data` from Dockerfile. Plus also printed `whoami` in gcsfuse.sh. User is `root`. Still does not work.
I don't think it's a permissions issue, but that something is wrong with the underlying mounting command.

Comment: What does `ls -l /dev/fuse` show?

Comment: Does <https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/321> help?

Comment: @user3840170 `/app $ ls -l /dev/fuse
ls: /dev/fuse: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update:

I solved it **mounting** GCS bucket in Cloud Run and **read/write** of object with the following changes:

- **Dockerfile:**

```
# https://github.com/chiaen/docker-gcsfuse
FROM golang:1.17.5-alpine as gcsfuse
RUN apk add --no-cache git
ENV GOPATH /go
RUN go get -u github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse

FROM composer:2 as vendor
COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock
RUN composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-interaction --prefer-dist

FROM craftcms/nginx:7.4

ENV MNT_DIR /mnt/gcs

USER root
RUN apk add --no-cache mysql-client postgresql-client ca-certificates fuse nano sudo tini bash
RUN mkdir -p $MNT_DIR
RUN chown www-data:www-data $MNT_DIR

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data --from=vendor /app/vendor/ /app/vendor/
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . .
COPY --from=gcsfuse /go/bin/gcsfuse /usr/local/bin
COPY supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisor.conf
```

- Added `-file-mode=777 -dir-mode=777` together with `gcsfuse` command in `gcsfuse.sh` to enable read/write inside the mounted directory of GCS bucket:

```
gcsfuse -o rw,allow_other -file-mode=777 -dir-mode=777 --foreground --debug_http --debug_gcs --debug_fuse --implicit-dirs $DISK_BUCKET $MNT_DIR
```

- Hardcoding the path (`/mnt/gcs/demo.txt` instead of `../storage/demo.txt`) for testing in the file `web/index.php`.

**Screenshot output:**

[image]

Comment: I think it is not a permissions error because `/dev/fuse` does not exist. 

Get this error here:
`sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper`
`sudo: a password is required` - 
`2021-12-21 10:44:23,121 INFO gave up: gcsfuse entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly` - 
`2021-12-21 10:44:23,122 INFO reaped unknown pid 19 (exit status 0)`

Comment: Plus also the file changes do not appear in the storage bucket admin interface.

Comment: @Fred I fixed it, please see the updated answer

Comment: I have also updated the Github repo! Thanks for your efforts!